# Как получить шестнадцатеричное число из строки в Python

Tags: python, hex

Я использую

```
hex('0x0ff')
```

но получается ошибка. Как правильно превратить строку в шестнадцатеричное число?

Comment: hex делает ровно наоборот, учитесь читать документацию. И ошибки.

Answer (score 3):

`hex` - для получения строки, описывающей 16-е число.

Для разбора строки с 16-м числом, вам нужно использовать функцию `int`:

```
print(int('0x0ff', 16))
# 255
```